# How do I show the tooltip when creating guides?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, guides

I am setting up guides for an art print in Photoshop. I want the guides to each be .025" on the top, bottom, left & right. I've noticed in some tutorial videos, when you pull down on the ruler to create a guide, a little tooltip pops up showing what the position of the guide is (Ex: Y: .025 in)... I do not have this option currently and I am wondering what I need to do to get it.

I want to be sure my guides are all exactly the same (.025") and right now I am just eyeballing it. I have CS5.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the tooltip wasn't there in CS5 I'm not sure, but you can create guides at precise locations by creating them through the View menu (*View → New Guide...*):

[image: New Guide Dialog]

Comment: The values are also visible in the information palette even if you do not have tooltips.

Answer (score 1):

I always create my guides by making a square selection and then dragging my guides out, from the rulers, to snap them to the edges of that selection.

- Ensure that your Rulers are on - <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
- Use the Marquee tool (<kbd>M</kbd>) and, holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, make a square selection of the size you'd like.  **EDIT** I forgot you don't have the tooltip, a workaround would be to manually set your selection's size at the top toolbar or use a square shape layer:
  [image]
- Click on your Rulers and drag the guides out, until they snap in place.  (Pro tip: place the selection at the upper-left corner and then repeat in the lower-right corner to place guides all around your document)

[image]

Comment: You're relying on the same tooltip that OP is missing to make your selection though ;)

Comment: (I'm being pedantic I know, It's a good tip +1)

Comment: @cai S*** I didn't even think of that haha.  You don't need to use the tool tip to make selections though, you could always enter the dimensions manually in the tool bar or even use a shape layer.  I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

There is also the fantastic tool [GuideGuide](http://guideguide.me/) for laying out lots (or just a few) guides at precise increments.